# How to remove specific children from an array depending on name

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, roblox

I'm creating an obby and for one of my levels I plan on making a platform that when stepped on changes places based on where I have these "Checkpoints" set for the platform to teleport to. I have a folder in the Explorer called "Levels" and inside the folder are the levels and I've added all the parts required to build the level attached to a parent part. I've added all the children to the levels parent part into an array using the :GetChildren() function and now I'm trying to sort through and remove any part that isn't a checkpoint. All checkpoints are called Tele1, Tele2, Tele3, etc... Currently I'm using Table.remove but I've heard that it's bad and should never ever be used but I'm also kind of a newbie so I don't know how else to go about this. Here's my code:

```
local checkpoints = game.Workspace.Levels.Level3:GetChildren()

for i, v in pairs(checkpoints) do
    if string.match(v.Name, "Tele") then
        
    else
        table.remove(checkpoints, i)
    end

    print(i, v)
end
```

printing to see if the tables been correctly sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as a side-note, I would recommend storing the folder of levels not in `game.Workspace` but in `ServerScriptStorage`. My example below is based on this.

Instead of removing parts from the table produced by the call to the `GetChildren()`, you could more easily iterate through that table and grab all parts that you consider checkpoints—e.g.:

```
-- The pattern that will be provided to string.match: it contains anchors
-- to the start and end of a string, and searches for 'Tele' followed by
-- one or more digits. This should be treated as a constant, hence the
-- capital letters.
local CHECKPOINT_PATTERN = "^Tele%d+$"

local serverStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local levels = serverStorage:FindFirstChild("Levels")
local level3 = levels:FindFirstChild("Level3")

-- Helper function to check if a particular part is a checkpoint.
-- Requires: part is a BasePart.
-- Effects : returns true if part.Name matches CHECKPOINT_PATTERN,
--           false otherwise.
local function is_checkpoint(part)
    return part.Name:match(CHECKPOINT_PATTERN) ~= nil
end

-- Get children of Level3, which should contain x number of checkpoints.
local children = level3:GetChildren()

-- Create a new table into which you will insert all parts you consider to
-- be checkpoints.
local checkpoints = {}

-- Iterate through the table children to find checkpoints.
for _, child in ipairs(children) do
    if (is_checkpoint(child)) then
        table.insert(checkpoints, child)
    end
end

-- To further abstract this process, the above for-loop could be placed
-- inside a function that returns a table of checkpoints; but, this is
-- entirely up to you and how you want to set up your code.

-- Continue with code, now that all checkpoints within Level3 have been
-- located and inserted into the table checkpoints.
```

This is far simpler than modifying the original table produced by `game.Workspace.Levels.Level3:GetChildren()`.

As an alternative, more advanced solution, you could, depending on how exactly you have set up your place, use the `CollectionService` to tag all parts that you consider to be checkpoints; you could them retrieve a table containing these checkpoints by calling `CollectionService:GetTagged(<tag>)`. See [this](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/CollectionService) page on the Roblox Wiki for reference.

Edit for clarification:

The variable—which I am treating as a constant—called `CHECKPOINT_PATTERN` is a string pattern; I use it in the same role as your `string.match(v.Name, "Tele")`, though my version is slightly different. To explain: the characters `^` and `$` are called anchors—the former means that the pattern match should start at the front of a string, and the latter does the same but indicates the end; the `"Tele"` is the same as in your original code; and `"%d+"` matches a digit one or more times. See [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) page for more information on string patterns in Lua.

As for the issue of putting your `Levels` folder in `ServerStorage`, this is a good idea as it better organizes assets in one location; and, it is more secure than storing things in, for instance, `game.Lighting`. I suggested this as a matter of good practice, but it of course depends on how your place is set up—if doing so removes your entire obby, then some restructuring of your place and code would be needed to make this work.

Comment: I'm not so advanced in programming just yet but I'm pretty sure I understand what's going on here however I just have a few question if that's okay. Firstly, what exactly is `^Tele%d+$` doing? I don't know what ^, %, d+$ means in this situation, and lastly when I place my Levels folder in Server Storage the entire obby just disappears off the map. How do I fix that? Also thank you for your help!

Comment: I just posted some edits. I hope they clear things up!

Comment: Okay so I created a new script and put it in ServerScriptService that goes like this. I created a script that copies my map and puts it into Workspace from ServerStorage. I created folders inside the Level folder to put all the pieces to my levels rather then anchoring all those pieces to a part in the game as a parent. I implemented your code and I'm getting an error that says "  12:52:00.155 - Workspace.Levels.Level3.Platform.Script:12: attempt to call a nil value"  and I think it has to do with the 
`return part.Name:Match(CHECKPOINT_PATTERN) ~= nil` part. I can't seem to solve this

Comment: `Match` should not be capitalized. Try `part.Name:match(CHECKPOINT_PATTERN) ~= nil`—notice the lowercase `match`.

Comment: It's so funny how something so small can break everything. This did solve the issue at hand but I hope you don't mind me asking one more question! I appreciate all the help you've given me already, this ones just for better clarification. I originally had the script attached to the platform part I wanted to work with but instead I put decided to put the script into ServerScriptService. Is this a better place for the script? Is it okay to attach the script to the part? And when working on the map should I have the map in workspace but put it in ServerStorage when I'm not working on the map?

Comment: It seems obvious that I should but I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong by simply shoving the Levels folder into ServerStorage and the entire map disappears. I've got my script that puts it in workspace upon running the game but I can't work on the map unless it's in workspace because it doesn't show up

Comment: Though inelegant, moving it between `game.Workspace` and `ServerStorage` when working on your levels is the simplest option.